# Windows 8.1 won't install update KB2919355

Tags: windows, updates

My `Windows Update` shows me that I got **3 important** updates:

```
KB2990967 (30KB)
KB3063843 (25KB)
KB2919355 (37KB)
```

When I press **Install** the updater does the installation and says: `The updates were successful. Succeeded: 3 updates`
The message looks OK, but, unfortunately, nothing is really installed. If I press `Check for Updates` button, it shows me exactly the same 3 updates again.
I was trying all possible solutions from Internet:

- Deleting `Software Distribution` folder
- Restarting `wuauserv`
- Performing different `DISM` commands
- Performing actions from Windows Help pages

None of the above did solve the issue.
In plus, I've tried downloading `KB2919355` manually from the official site, but as soon as I try to install it I got an error message: `The update is not applicable for your computer`.
The strange thing about `Windows Update` that it shows absolutely incorrect sizes of updates. For example, `KB2919355` has a real size of **600+MB** when you download it from official site, but `Windows Update` shows just **37KB**.

Here are my `CBS Logs`: https://www.mediafire.com/?sosbr9vt8gsr5po

**Update 1** Added VSLogs: http://www.mediafire.com/file/ohdi16fj1a94hdk/vslogs.zip

Could anyone suggest what I can do to install `KB2919355`?

Comment: hide the update KB2919355. you likely already have this update, because without it you don't get new updates.

Comment: @magicandre1981, Unfortunately, I don't have this update. I need it to install `Visual Studio 2015` and it's installer is saying that I need to install `KB2919355` first...

Comment: run **reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" | findstr BuildLabEx** and look if the value after 9600. is larger compared to 17031. if this is the case, you already have the update

Comment: @magicandre1981, the number is: **18264**. This is very strange, because I'm trying to install Visual Studio 2015 and it says that it needs`KB2919355` which is not installed on my system. Very strange.

Comment: @magicandre1981, how's this possible that Visual Studio 2015 installer continues saying that it needs this update to be installed? Is it possible to do something with it?

Comment: run this tool to get all vs setup logs: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12493 and share the generated zip

Comment: @magicandre1981, I've updated starting post with the zip file you've asked. Thank you.

Comment: this is really wired. Extract the KB2919355 MSU and run this commadn: dism /online /add-package /packagepath:C:\Windows8.1-KB2919355-x64.cab to install the update again.

Comment: @magicandre1981, Thank you for your help. After trying to solve the issue for 2 days with hundreds of different solutions with the help of different people - the problem was not fixed. That's why I had to reinstall Windows.

Comment: @magicandre1981, trying to extract update and install using DISM didn't work neither :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying to solve the issue for 2 days with hundreds of different solutions with the help of different people - the problem was not fixed.
**I had to reinstall Windows**

Comment: yeah, this is sometimes easier. the log said it checked for the KB2919355 data in registry and they were missing. have you used any "tuning" tools?

Comment: @magicandre1981, Yes, I was using CCleaner and, I'm not sure if it was on this PC, tool to clean SxS folder. So I assume they might've broken registry...

Comment: yes, this broke windows. don't use it any longer!

Answer (score -1):

This is a pig of a problem to solve; it took many days of frustration, determination and combinations of other suggestions to solve. This what finally worked for me...
Steps are:
Download and save the standalone version of
windows8.1-kb2919355-x64_e6f4da4d33564419065a7370865faacf9b40ff72

You can find it here:  https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/search.aspx?q=kb2919355

And also
WindowsUpdateDiagnostic.diagcab

Direct download here
https://delivery2.filecroco.com/kits_5/WindowsUpdateDiagnostic.diagcab

Then - turn off your network and turn off Auto-updates - change to Never get updates.
Reboot.
Run WindowsUpdateDiagnostic.diagcab

then, after it has done its thing (takes a while) - DON'T SKIP THIS CRUCIAL STEP -
****  Reboot ****

Then Run your copy of windows8.1-kb2919355-x64_e6f4da4d33564419065a7370865faacf9b40ff72
(Ensure that you are not on line and updates is still turned off... otherwise that auto process will take over again from this one and fail.)

This was the only process of many that I tried, that finally installed this update.
Check that it is in the Installed Updates file.

Important last steps:- go to the Updates Settings, return update setting to normal and untick that prompt to install important updates - it is now out of date.
Then click Check for updates.
After this I was able to get the other updates.